# symtable module in Python3 - Why does symtable.Symbol.is_global() in Python3 return False for a symbol defined at the top level?

Tags: python, module

I'm rather new to Python and I'm studying the symbol tables using the symtable module. I do not understand a specific behavior of the method symtable.Symbol.is_global(). Python 3 reference manual says it returns True if the symbol is a global variable. However, when I run the following code, I get False for the variable "x" that is defined at the top level. I suppose 'x' is a global variable in the code (sorry if I'm wrong).

Could anyone explain this or know related documents?

I use Python 3.8.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Thanks in advance.

```py
>>> import symtable
>>> code = """
... x=5
... """
>>> tbl = symtable.symtable(code,"main.py","exec")
>>> tbl.get_type()
'module'
>>> tbl.get_symbols()
[<symbol 'x'>]
>>> top_syms = tbl.get_symbols()
>>> top_syms[0]
<symbol 'x'>
>>> top_syms[0].is_global()
False
>>> top_syms[0].is_local()
True
>>> tbl.get_name()
'top'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this behavior.

```
>>> import symtable
>>> code = """x=5"""
>>> tbl = symtable.symtable(code,"main.py","exec")
>>> tbl.get_symbols()
[<symbol 'x'>]
>>> top_syms = tbl.get_symbols()
>>> xsymb = top_syms[0]
>>> xsymb.is_global()
True
```

A very nice read is Eli Bendersky's blog post on symtables ([part1](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/09/18/python-internals-symbol-tables-part-1), [part2](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/09/20/python-internals-symbol-tables-part-2)) He also has a nice function to inspect symbols (public domain):

```
def describe_symbol(sym):
    assert type(sym) == symtable.Symbol
    print("Symbol:", sym.get_name())

    for prop in [
            'referenced', 'imported', 'parameter',
            'global', 'declared_global', 'local',
            'free', 'assigned', 'namespace']:
        if getattr(sym, 'is_' + prop)():
            print('    is', prop)
```

Which for me also consistently shows that x is global:

```
>>> describe_symbol(xsymb)
Symbol: x
    is global
    is local
    is assigned
```

Comment: Having your answer, I tested several different versions of Python 3 (3.9.5, 3.8.10, 3.8.0, 3.7.10, 3.6.13) using Anaconda on Win 10. I found is_global returns True in ver. 3.9.5, 3.8.10 but False in 3.8.0, 3.7.10, and 3.6.13. It's good to know it's a version dependent issue.

Comment: That is indeed very strange. Hope someone can explain this. (I use 3.8.8)